# Python-list in the query

Tags: python, plugins

I am working with python plugins.I used list to store some values as below:

```
known_stn.append('1')
known_stn.append('2')
```

My query is

```
query=("SELECT survey, station FROM stat WHERE stat.station IN (%s) AND station.survey = '2011410'" %known_stn)
```

Error occurs for `WHERE station.station IN (['1', '2'])`,as list contains [] brackets.
I tried replacing those brackets but they doesnt get replace.

Is there any other data structure to use?? Or way out to replace square brackets...

Comment: "Python plugins" doesn't mean anything afaik. What are you using to interface with SQL?

Comment: I am using postgresSQL as database.and pyqt4 designer for GUI.....

Comment: Don't format your query strings yourself; that's asking for an SQL injection attack. Use the built-in formatting in whatever you're using to execute the query. (The below answers are correct in that you need to join the list into a string first, though.)

Comment: For example, in any module using the [Python Database API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) you should write `cursor.execute(query, parameters)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format your list as a string *before* you substitute it into your template string:

```
"where (%s) blah" % ', '.join(map(str,known_stn))
```

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

`map(str,known_stn)` converts the elements themselves to a string, before joining.

Also, heed the warnings about SQL injection.

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert the list to a string first:

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3]
>>> str(my_list)
'[1, 2, 3]'
>>> map(str, my_list)
['1', '2', '3']
>>> ','.join(map(str, my_list))
'1,2,3'
>>> 'select ... where foo in (%s)' % ','.join(map(str, my_list))
'select ... where foo in (1,2,3)'
```